# Wireless is disabled by hardware switch. Wifi doesn't work! (hard blocked: yes,soft blocked :no, hp pavillion g6 2237, Ubuntu 12.04)?

Tags: wireless

I dual installed Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 8 with dual boot option.

Wireless disabled by hardware switch.

How to turn on the WiFi?

I tried following commands:

```
gaurav@gaurav-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 13ba:0017 Unknown PS/2 Keyboard+Mouse Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c1e Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc.
```

```
gaurav@gaurav-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM   Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200/2nd Generation Core Processor Family PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor  Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Panther Point High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Panther Point LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Panther Point 6 port SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Panther Point SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD] nee ATI Thames XT/GL [Radeon HD 7600M Series]
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. Device 3290
07:00.1 Bluetooth: Ralink corp. Device 3298
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller (rev 05)
09:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5229 (rev 01)
```

```
gaurav@gaurav-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo rfkill unblock all
gaurav@gaurav-HP-Pavilion-g6-Notebook-PC:~$ rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: yes
```

**wireless card**

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
```

Comment: as always: 1. check for a switch on the side of your machine. 2. check Fn+F{number} for the wireless. 3. check BIOS for a wireless setting.

Comment: it didn't help.what more data you want regarding the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Install all the necessary compilation tools at first and download the latest driver from its git repository:(EXAMPLE FOR TL-WN725N)

```
$$ sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-generic git

$$ mkdir ~/RTL8188EU

$$ cd ~/RTL8188EU

$$ git clone git://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
```

---

Afterwards, the driver can be compiled and installed:

Go into the folder and execute following commands.

```
$$ make
$$ sudo make install
```

---

The new kernel module can be loaded via modprobe and can be installed system-wide for automatic loading:

```
$$ sudo depmod -a
$$ sudo update-initramfs -u
$$ sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

---

(Automatic boot:)
To enable the module at each boot add your module to /etc/modules

```
$$ echo 8188eu >> /etc/modules
```

---

Run command

```
$$ lspci -v
```

and search for your built-in wifi card...

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation WiFi Link 5100 AGN
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 47
    Memory at d6500000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [e0] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-24-d6-ff-ff-3e-5e-a4
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

---

Now block that card....

```
$$ sudo echo "blacklist iwlwifi" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

---

Now run

```
$$ lsmod | grep sony
```

replace sony with company name of your laptop....

Block your laptop (like for sony vaio it is "sony_laptop"....

```
$$ sudo echo "blacklist sony_laptop" >> /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
```

---

DONE..!!!

Now reboot...
You will be able to run your wifi adapter even if your wireless switch is turned off....!!

Answer (score 0):

I have the pavilion g6. The wireless switch in linux is the f12 key **without** the fn switch